# Gson - Conditional JSON Deserialization (Sanity Checks)

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

I have code in my android project that correctly deserializes json into POJO's using gson.  I wish to add some condtional acceptance checks (sanity checks) to the incoming json.  For instance, with the data structure below, I wish for the gson parser to only add objects where the start date < end date.  I know I could iterate through the list after it is populated to remove invalid items, but I was wondering if there was any way to reject the items on the fly.  Any help would be appreciated.

**Example JSON**

```
{
  "Items" : [
     {
        "Name" : "Example Name",
        "Start" : "2010-10-16 10:00:00",
        "End" : "2011-03-20 17:00:00",
        <other fields>
    }, 
    <several more items>
  ]
}
```

**ItemList.java**

```
public class ItemList {
    private List<ItemHeader> Items;

    public void setItemHeaders(List<ItemHeader> headers) {
        Items = headers;
    }

    public List<ItemHeader> getItemHeaders() {
        return Items;
    }
}
```

**ItemHeader.java** has fields for name, start, end and all the other fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to write your own deserializer and have it throw an exception when your condition isn't met.

http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer

I don't know that you *should* do this, but it's possible.